# How to connect storage to web server with sshfs?

Tags: routing, sshfs

I started to installed a vmware web server. The server first was in the local lan. (192.168.137.200) At this time I could attach (mount) a sshfs folder to the server from the host machine (192.168.137.211). Later I set the fix public IP (193.6.179.221) and I could not connect the sshfs folder anymore. I think there is something with the routing, but what?
thx,  István

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu?

Comment: yes. Why do you ask?

Comment: This looks more like a routing network related question rather than Ubuntu question.

Comment: Does the web server have the IP 193.6.179.221? Either add a second network interface, which you connect to your local interface, or configure some kind of port forwarding. Anyway, I've never been in a situation where you set a public IP inside a NAT...

Comment: This situation is bit more difficult. The host machine has 2 NIC. One for the local net and one to let out the virtual webserver. I had the same idea to add a second NIC to the web server toward the local net. I think the problem here that there is no route back from the web towards the local machine where the shared folder (storage) is. If I add a second NIC do I have to set something in the routing table?